# Show that there exists subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $U\cap \text{null} \ T=\{0\}$ and $\text{range} \ T=\{T(u):u \in U\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional and that $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Show that there exists subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $U\cap \text{null} \ T=\{0\}$ and $\text{range} \ T=\{T(u):u \in U\}$. My attempt is to construct the subspace $U$. I would like to know if my proof holds, please.

Suppose that $\dim V = \dim W$ (the case $\dim V<\dim W$ and $\dim W<\dim V$ can be proven similiarly).

Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$, $(u_1,...,u_n)$ a basis of $U$ and $(w_1,...,w_m)$ a basis of $W$ . As $(u_1,...,u_n)$ is linearly independent in $U$ it is linearly independent in $V$. Thus, we can extend $(u_1,...,u_n)$ to a basis of $V$: $\mathcal{B}_{V}:=(u_1,...,u_n,v_{n+1},...,v_m)$.

Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ be defined as

$T(u_i)=w_i, T(v_j)=0$ with $i=1,...,n$ and $j=n+1,...,m$

By construction $\text{range}\ T= \{T(u):u \in U\}$ and $U \cap \text{null} \ T=\{0\}$. We conclude that there exists subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $U\cap \text{null} \ T=\{0\}$ and $\text{range} \ T=\{T(u):u \in U\}$.

I am not sure if my proof is valid as I never proved things by direct construction.

Comment: Given $T$, we are supposed to construct a subspace $U$. I would start with a basis for null $T$ and extend

Comment: You proved that, given a subspace $U$ of $V$, there exists $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$ such that $U \cap \operatorname{null}T = \{0\}$ and $\operatorname{range} T = \{T(u) : u \in U\}$, but that is not what the exercise asked for.